# How to send the values from PendingIntent to Broadcast

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I try  to send the values from PendingIntent to Broadcast but I can't. This my code:

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
  calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, alarmDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity_Main.this, SampleBootReceiver.class);
  myIntent.putExtra("ID", 1234);

  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Activity_Main.this,0, myIntent, 0);
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 20000, pendingIntent);
```

And This my BroadCast:

```
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int i=  intent.getExtras().getInt("ID");
        Log.w("Sample",""+ i);
        Intent a =new Intent(context,RSSPullService.class);
        a.putExtra("ID",i);
        context.startService(a);
   }
}
```

I get the value of `i` as `0`. I don't understand why. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you add your service and receiver in your Manifest File?

Answer (score 2):

Since the only thing changing in the Intent is the extras. So the PendingIntent.getActivity(...) factory method is simply re-using the old intent as an optimization.

Change this line,

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Activity_Main.this,0, myIntent, 0);
```

to,

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Activity_Main.this,0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

See [FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) reference.

Comment: Actually using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is a better choice, but either should work.

Comment: Yup, you are right. He had problem with the already existing intent. So I thought maybe creating a whole new intent would help. Updated my answer. Thanks for the tip.